# svn; utilize lazy copies for existing versions (branches) on initial commit

Tags: svn

Hey guys, I'm moving to subversion.

I have 2 different websites based on the same codebase with heavy differences (they differ about 15%). Sites both have >10K files. When I develop something for 'A', I sometimes synch 'B' with changes, or changes may be specific to 'A', or vice versa.

So I think it will be logical to have them as two branches in the same repo, and the trunk may be empty for now.

I know a similar compression will apply for the svn file system anyway, but will it be completely ok if I initially commit these as two branches? Or should I;

- create & commit the default folder structure,
- commit 'A' as the first branch,
- copy 1st branch as 2nd branch
- update the working copy,
- delete the 2nd branch in the working copy,
- copy 'B' site to the 2nd branch in the working copy,
- commit

so the server will know (or not?) unchanged files between branches, and keep them as lazy copies?

Btw, some file dates may differ though they have the same content, as usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the right track in order to minimize the storage-amount within the SVN.

I'd recommend the following technique:

- commit "A" as a branch in the repo
- remote copy (aka branch) "A" into new branch "B" - A and B are now completely the same
- **check out** "B" as a new project/folder (outside your "A"-working dir)
- add the changed files into "B" ( I'm pretty sure the modify-date won't count as a diff)
- commit "B"

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Stefan, nice description! =)

Comment: wow, not as easy as it seems =) instead of adding changed files into 'B', I intended to empty 'B', put all files and commit, in order to get rid of deleted files and folders. Because of missing .svn folders, this didn't work. Then I synchronized working copy with original 'B' folder, ignoring 'svn' folders, so I was able to replace changed files and get rid of deleted files. However now, there should be tens of folders which are empty and need to be deleted, but the diff program doesn't show them as they have 'svn' folders in them, so are not really empty.

Comment: I'm still wondering if directly commiting two branches will do the same thing. Like, svn can be keeping every file/part only once in the repo, and just inserting handlers into the file system in all revisions. If it works this way, no matter we commit the same file in two different places, or at two different revisions, or make a branch, it would result in the same pattern in the database. I have to try this if I can find some time to analyze the db.

Answer (score 0):

Did some expirements. Well, turns out SVN always keeps a single copy of a content, whether a file with the same content is commited in the same revision, in a different revision, or is branched from another file. They all reference a hash, and get the content from the first commit.

So, in the means of size, an initial commit with all branches is completely ok, even results in a slightly smaller repo size due to less revisions.

Going with the 'branching' path adds a branch info into the revision. However, it's only useful for human readable reference, and I think will not be important or even meaningful in the initial commit. It can also be written into the commit description if wanted.